# Published WebForm malfunctioning: COMBOBOX--QUERY combination?

Tags: ms-access, binding, combobox, webforms, reference

I've created a really simple access WebDB, which contains:

A) a table (that stores dates and grades of some courses).
B) one form that the teachers use as input (date and grades).
C) another form that is used as an output, to show the grades (by choosing the date from a combobox)

---

For having a report with the results of every search I make, i created a query, and then the report.

After choosing the date from the combobox, i press a command button that runs the report based on the query.

I have set the Combobox to show the dates from the main table. The thing looks impossible to me, is to make the query run each time with the criteria chosen by the combobox.

I have set to the "Where Condition" (under the button's Macro) the following :

```
[DateField]=[Forms].[FormThatContainsTheCombo].[Combo]
```

and on my computer EVERYTHING WORKS FINE...

NOW THE REASON I ASK DOR YOUR HELP:

When i publish all that on the sharepoint server site and press the button, the following error occurs :

Invalid reference 'Forms.FormThatContainsTheCombo.Combo' in expression. You may have attempted to use an undeclared parameter or a field that is not bound to a control on the form or report.

I am sure that for most of you , its an easy job to help me on that.
I will be honest, it's the first project i got from my job and is very very important for me to make it..  :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that code is your where clause, then it should work. If the report is based on a web query with that forms! as a condition then you MUST remove it. So you need to use a "where" clause of the OpenReport command here. This simply means that a [forms]![SomeFormName] refs in web query is NOT allowed.

Assuming the above issues, then then two more things I can think of that would cause this to fail:

You placed the form inside of a navigation form. This in effect means your form is now in a sub-form and your forms ref in the filter command is thus now wrong.

In fact, due to above nasty issue, I would as a general rule stuff the value from a control INTO a local variable and THEN use that variable in the filter expression. The reason for this is many, but one bonus is that you don't then have the forms reference in your code hard coded. A filter can accept a control but it MUST be hard coded fully qualified forms ref. However the filter command can ALSO use a local or global variable.

It turns out (thankfully) that you can stuff values from forms controls into a variable WITHOUT the need for a qualified forms ref. So you can just use the control name. This quite much gives you the same as "me" in VBA and the result is forms neutral code here. So this "extra" step is strongly recommended.

This approach thus allows you to copy the form, rename the form, or even use the form inside of a subform (and that means the new web navigation form) all without the need to modify your code and the form name.

The next issue is web based applications are FAR more sensitive to data types. So what this means is that if your combo box is NOT bound then it is likely NOT returning a date data type value. This will then case the filter to fail web side.

Access in the client side will often "cast" the data type for you, but for web this is less forgiving.

One simple approach here is the property sheet for the combo box (format tab), set the format of the combo box to date (try short date). This should fix your issue.

I would in addition also use the above set var idea to remove the hard coded forms ref and name.

So your code should look like this:

```
 SetLocalVar  (dtUserDate,[myComboBox])

 OpenReport (myReport, [InvoiceDate] = [LocalVars]![dtUserDate], Normal)
```

Note that if the combo box is bound to an underlying column in the database, then setting of the data format in the combo box property sheet is not required. However this is likely an unbound combo box and thus setting of the data type is a must.

This data type issue also applies to text boxes when you filter number column (set to general number in the format tab). (or wrap the expression in CDbl() to cast it to a long data type).

For dates you can also use dateSerial() command to force a date type, but this is likely not going to make sense from a combo box.

So at the end of the day here, when using un-bound controls on forms, and using such values for filters, then pay close attention to the data type.

As noted, this is not generally a issue/problem with bound controls, but for un-bound then the expression often takes on the wrong data type and while the Access client does a better job of "casting" the data type, the web side of things is more sensitive.